# venue and location do not display correctly

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to display the data from database in different table but the venue and location do not display correctly.
Here is my code

```
<?php
    include "database_conn.php";

    if(isset($_GET['eventID'])){
        $id = $_GET["eventID"]; //get event id
    }
    else {
        header ("Refresh : 5; url=chooseEventList.php");//redirect to choose title
        die ("Please use the Choose Event Title List");
    }

    //get event id
    $id = $_GET["eventID"];

    //select event
    $sqlEvent = "SELECT * FROM te_events  , te_venue , te_category 
                 WHERE eventID =".$id
                ;


    //excute sql statemente
    $event = mysqli_query($conn , $sqlEvent) or die (mysqli_error($conn));

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($event) or die (mysqli_error($conn));

    //extract each field$
        $id         = $row  ["eventID"];
        $title      = $row  ["eventTitle"];
        $desc       = $row  ["eventDescription"];
        $venueId    = $row  ["venueID"];
        $venue      = $row  ["venueName"];
        $location   = $row  ["location"];
        $categoryId = $row  ["catID"];
        $eStart     = $row  ["eventStartDate"];
        $eEnd       = $row  ["eventEndDate"];
        $ePrice     = $row  ["eventPrice"]; 

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title> event details</title>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
</head>
<body>    
<fieldset>
    <legend>Event details</legend>      
        <div>
            Event title                 
<input type ="text" name ="eventTitle" value="<?=$title?>"readonly/>
        </div>          
        <div>
            Description
                <textarea style="resize:none" name="desc" rows="10" cols="40"><?=$desc?></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            Venue Name
                <input type = "text" name="venueName" value="<?=$venue?>"readonly/>
        </div>          
        <div>
            Location
                <input type="text" name="location" value="<?=$location?>"readonly/>
        </div>          
        <div>
            Event Start Date
                <input type="text" name="eventStartDate" value="<?=$eStart?>"readonly/>
        </div>          
        <div>
            Event End Date
                <input type="text" name="eventEndDate" value="<?=$eEnd?>"readonly/>
        </div>          
        <div>
            Event Price
                <input type="text" name="eventPrice" value="<?=$ePrice?>"readonly/>
        </div>
            </fieldset>    
</body>
</html>
```

I think my problem is held in the $sqlEvent.

when I remove the `'WHERE eventID = " .$id;'` , it displays the same details when I click on the event title in previous page.

do tell me if previous page is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your sql is wrong you should use join

```
SELECT * FROM te_events 
INNER JOIN te_venue ON te_events.tvId = te_venue.tvId 
INNER JOIN te_category ON te_events.tcId = te_category.tcId 
WHERE te_events.eventID =".$id
```